# Filter recycleview using searchview android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I want to implement the `searchView` widget inside the toolbar to filter the `recyclerview`. But i got an error message.

this is my code:

**PasalAdapter.java**

```
public class PasalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {

private List<PasalItem> mPasalItem;

public PasalAdapter(List<PasalItem> PasalItem) {
    mPasalItem = new ArrayList<>(PasalItem);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
    final PasalItem getPasal = mPasalItem.get(i);
    itemViewHolder.bind(getPasal);
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPasalItem.size();
}

/** Filter Logic**/
public void animateTo(List<PasalItem> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);

}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<PasalItem> newModels) {


    for (int i = mPasalItem.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final PasalItem model = mPasalItem.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<PasalItem> newModels) {

    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final PasalItem model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!mPasalItem.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<PasalItem> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final PasalItem model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = mPasalItem.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public PasalItem removeItem(int position) {
    final PasalItem model = mPasalItem.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, PasalItem model) {
    mPasalItem.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final PasalItem model = mPasalItem.remove(fromPosition);
    mPasalItem.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}

}
```

**ItemViewHolder.java**

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private TextView pasal_TextView;
private TextView bab_TextView;

public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    pasal_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx_pasal);
    bab_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx_bab);

}

public void bind(PasalItem pasalItem) {
    pasal_TextView.setText(pasalItem.getPasal());
    bab_TextView.setText(pasalItem.getBab());

}

}
```

**PasalItem.Java**

```
public class PasalItem {
private String pasal;
private String bab;

public String getPasal() {
    return pasal;
}


public void setPasal(String pasal) {
    this.pasal = pasal;
}


public String getBab() {
    return bab;
}

public void setBab(String bab) {
    this.bab = bab;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.pasal;

}

}
```

**Edit**

```
12-23 07:55:31.062 29266-29266/id.rsspdev.uud E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at id.rsspdev.uud.adapter.ItemViewHolder.bind(ItemViewHolder.java:26)
at id.rsspdev.uud.adapter.PasalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PasalAdapter.java:28)
at id.rsspdev.uud.adapter.PasalAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PasalAdapter.java:17)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:761)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14099)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4464)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
at android.view.
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Before I even look on the code, What's the error message?

Comment: Post your code where SearchView events are defined.

Comment: I just edit my question,, please help me

Comment: From the stacktrace, the error is coming from getPasal in the bind method     itemViewHolder.bind(getPasal); 
What code is entailed in getPasal?

Comment: That is returning a null object reference

Answer (score 2):

What is happening in your RecyclerView is similar to this question here:

[Getting position of View in onCreateViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840394/getting-position-of-view-in-oncreateviewholder)

Where recyclerview doesn't maintain a static position index. If you don't want to lose your item when recyclerview does this you can't utilize the given position.

try:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
     final PasalItem getPasal = mPasalItem.get(itemViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
     itemViewHolder.bind(getPasal);
}
```